# iOS XCode Simulator with Bluetooth 4.0

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a question about using BLE with the iOS Simulator.

I followed these instructions to set up XCode simulator with BLE:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2295/_index.html

I use a Macbook Pro Retina with built-in BLE and a CSR USB BLE Dongle. Mac OS X discovers the USB Dongle, because it is shown in the System Information.

After that I enter this command:

sudo nvram bluetoothHostControllerSwitchBehavior="never"

to have the Broadcom chip again.

When I start XCode there is no way to turn on Bluetooth, it is always rotating and I always get this on debug: -[CentralManager state] will return the CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff

So what the problem here?

Thanks for help!

Bye

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Unplugging and then plugging back in the CSR USB BLE Dongle caused the simulator to immediately switch from rotating to on.